# How can I store a graph and run page rank like analytics on it hbase?

Tags: data-structures, graph, hadoop, graph-theory, hbase

Sorry if this question seems a bit complex but I think its all related so I wanted try to get the answer in one shot.  Basically I have a layered graph*, that has various sets of data that are connected to only the next set of data(so set1 has vertexes that have edges to set2, and so on but set1 has nothing connecting to set3 or anything other than set2.  It might be relevant not sure). Generally, you can think of my data as one massive family tree(every set I add about a billion nodes) that I keep loading new generations with every new set(families create new families and no edges go backwards).

I have an Hbase/hadoop system running and I know how to use java to add columns and values, but what I don't know how to do is:

1. add data to hbase in a graph type format(since its hbase, I want to load it in a way that I can add a ton of data and it'll scale..unlike other databases that limit graphs to the size of the system). I know how to add data but don't understand how to do it in a scalable graph way.
2. Once the graph is loaded I want to know how to apply some kind of analytics to it. Pagerank is popular so I thought I would say it, but pretty much anything that is based on processing a graph.

I guess the simplified way of asking the question is how to do I specifically get a graph into hbase and once its there how do I analyze it?  Is there a tutorial? There's a lot of hbase information on the internet(I read the hbase book) but I could not find anything specific to graphs. I found, [giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/), but I don't think it can connect to hbase(yet).  Seeing how hadoop/hbase are versions of mapreduce/bigtables I suspect there is a way to process graphs I'm just not having luck finding anything.

*A layered graph is a directed graph with a level for different set of vertex's, like so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question on SO could help:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865738/is-it-possible-to-store-graphs-hbase-if-so-how-do-you-model-the-database-to-sup/9867563#9867563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865738/is-it-possible-to-store-graphs-hbase-if-so-how-do-you-model-the-database-to-sup)

This part of my answer to this question might be of use.

> Using HBase/Accumulo as input to giraph has been submitted recently (7
>   Mar 2012) as a new feature request to Giraph: [HBase/Accumulo Input
>   and Output formats](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GIRAPH-153) (GIRAPH-153)

Comment: Thank you Binary, I did see your answer but  I'm looking for something that allows me to scale and run analytics on a graph right now.  Who knows how long it takes for the request to be production ready.

Comment: Sure, since even Giraph is quite far off hitting verison 1.0 these additions might take a while to be officially added, so you could just try out the input/output formatters submitted with the request. If that doesn't work, I would think about why you need to put your data in hbase? If you want to do anything remotely complex or iterative, hbase wont give you much. You'd be better storing your data on HDFS, using Giraph and maybe then storing processed results in hbase if you need fast access to them.

Comment: ahhhhh...you just triggered a light bulb..I thought I needed hbase as a form of persistent storage on HDFS, but are you saying Giraph can do it also?  Looking at my requirements above, can I store a graph and analyze it(at scale) simply using hadoop(HDFS) and Giraph?   Sorry I've seen so many in-memory graph databases that I thought I needed Hbase for persistence.  Is this assumption true?

Comment: The usual way to use giraph is to just store your data on HDFS and load it into giraph from there. I would look at the standard input formatter for giraph which just reads data straight of HDFS. Sounds like this might be what you're after, and you dont need to worry about the NoSQL stuff that distracts from the actual graph work :)

Comment: I thought I needed some kind of database as a storage engine for the nodes of the graph.  I'm not sure I quite understand though, Is Giraph a storage engine and a graph processing engine or is it just a graph processing engine that requires me to load all the data each time I want to use it?  Also does it scale with Hadoop?  The reason I ask is I'm purposing we use it at a bio research lab and they are going to get billion+ nodes everyday so one machine won't be able to handle it, will Giraph work in this case?

Comment: I'm still confused,  Can I use giraph to store the graphs? and can it scale indefinitely(as I provide more cpu's)? Most of the samples I have seen haven't been more than a few million.

Answer (score 0):

We use giraph in this way, it only store minimum data in each vertex, and then run the graph algorithm with giraph, then we assemble the result with rich data using pig, for page rank algo, each vertex only needs to store vertex id, rank, thus it could scale to almost billion level.